# Почему оптимизация цикла для O2 лучше, чем O3?

Tags: c++, c, ассемблер, оптимизация

Почему эта функция

```
void add(int count, float* results, const float* dataA, const float* dataB) {
  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    results[i] = dataA[i] + dataB[i];
}
```

при `-O2` оптимизируется в меньший код

```
add(int, float*, float const*, float const*):
        test    edi, edi
        jle     .L1
        movsx   rdi, edi
        xor     eax, eax
.L3:
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rdx+rax*4]
        addss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rcx+rax*4]
        movss   DWORD PTR [rsi+rax*4], xmm0
        add     rax, 1
        cmp     rdi, rax
        jne     .L3
.L1:
        ret
```

чем при `-O3`

```
add(int, float*, float const*, float const*):
        mov     r8d, edi
        mov     rdi, rdx
        mov     rdx, rcx
        test    r8d, r8d
        jle     .L1
        lea     rcx, [rcx+4]
        mov     rax, rsi
        sub     rax, rcx
        cmp     rax, 8
        seta    cl
        cmp     r8d, 1
        setne   al
        test    cl, al
        je      .L3
        lea     rcx, [rdi+4]
        mov     rax, rsi
        sub     rax, rcx
        cmp     rax, 8
        jbe     .L3
        lea     eax, [r8-1]
        mov     r9d, r8d
        cmp     eax, 2
        jbe     .L11
        mov     ecx, r8d
        xor     eax, eax
        shr     ecx, 2
        sal     rcx, 4
.L5:
        movups  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdi+rax]
        movups  xmm2, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+rax]
        addps   xmm0, xmm2
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax], xmm0
        add     rax, 16
        cmp     rax, rcx
        jne     .L5
        test    r8b, 3
        je      .L1
        mov     ecx, r8d
        mov     r9d, r8d
        and     ecx, -4
        sub     r9d, ecx
        mov     eax, ecx
        cmp     r9d, 1
        je      .L7
.L4:
        movq    xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdi+rcx*4]
        movq    xmm1, QWORD PTR [rdx+rcx*4]
        addps   xmm0, xmm1
        movlps  QWORD PTR [rsi+rcx*4], xmm0
        test    r9b, 1
        je      .L1
        and     r9d, -2
        add     eax, r9d
.L7:
        cdqe
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rdi+rax*4]
        addss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rdx+rax*4]
        movss   DWORD PTR [rsi+rax*4], xmm0
        ret
.L3:
        xor     eax, eax
.L9:
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rdi+rax*4]
        addss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rdx+rax*4]
        movss   DWORD PTR [rsi+rax*4], xmm0
        add     rax, 1
        cmp     r8, rax
        jne     .L9
.L1:
        ret
.L11:
        xor     ecx, ecx
        xor     eax, eax
        jmp     .L4
```

https://godbolt.org/z/W1jjrPE6a

Comment: а по какому критерию вы даёте оценку «лучше»?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin короче, быстрее

Comment: @steff из того, что код короче, не следует, что он быстрее. Сравните скорость исполнения и проверьте себя.

Comment: @gbg почему тогда меньше, если не быстрее?

Comment: Потому что более длинный вариант кода, если его внимательно почитать, испольует векторные инструкции разной размерности для разных случаев, а значит, за одну итерацию цикла он может складывать сразу несколько элементов.

Comment: А из того, что код длиннее, тоже не следует, что он быстрее.

Comment: А вот код нулевой длины часто бывает самым быстрым:) в любом случае, нужно бенчмаркать на реальной системе.

Answer (score 1):

"Короткий код" использует "одиночные/single" векторные инструкции, низводя таким образом себя до "обычного кода", "длинный код" проверят можно ли применить параллельное вычисление и если да то ускоряет себя многократно. Более высокие "расходы" на вход в цикл несопоставима меньше чем выигрыш от параллельного вычисления.